# replace specific text in ruby using regex

Tags: ruby, regex, rubular

In ruby, I'm trying to replace the below url's **bolded** portion with new numbers:

> /ShowForum-g1-i12105-**o20**-TripAdvisor_Support.html

How would I target and replace the **-o20-**
with -o30- or -o40- or -o1200- while leaving the rest of the url
intact? The urls could be anything, but I'd like to be able to find this exact pattern of -o20- and replace it with whatever number I want.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will work.

```
url = "/ShowForum-g1-i12105-o20-TripAdvisor_Support.html"
url = url.gsub!(/-o20-/, "something_to_replace") 
puts "url is : #{url}"
```

Output:

```
sh-4.3$ ruby main.rb                                                                                                                                                 
url is : /ShowForum-g1-i12105something_to_replaceTripAdvisor_Support.html
```

Comment: This gives me an error: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
        secondUrl.gsub(/­\-o20\­-/,'-o90-'­)
                                              ^

Answer (score 1):

```
url[/(?<=-o)\d+(?=-)/] = ($&.to_i + 10).to_s
```

The snippet above will replace the number inplace with (itself + 10).

```
url = '/ShowForum-g1-i12105-o20-TripAdvisor_Support.html'

url[/(?<=-o)\d+(?=-)/] = ($&.to_i + 10).to_s
#⇒ "30"
url
#⇒ "/ShowForum-g1-i12105-o30-TripAdvisor_Support.html"
url[/(?<=-o)\d+(?=-)/] = ($&.to_i + 10).to_s
#⇒ "40"
url
#⇒ "/ShowForum-g1-i12105-o40-TripAdvisor_Support.html"
```

To replace with whatever number you want:

```
url[/(?<=-o)\d+(?=-)/] = "500"
url
#⇒ "/ShowForum-g1-i12105-o500-TripAdvisor_Support.html"
```

More info: [`String#[]=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D).

Comment: Mudsie, my reading of the question is that `"-o20"` is a given string, which of course simplifies the question considerably.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I have read “I target and replace the -o20- with -o30- or -o40- or -o1200-” as the goal is to update the number, so I did my best to make it easy :)